# How to approach an inverse image problem with sinusoids?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm beginning some work on finding the inverse images of systems of equations that are primarily based on sinusoids.  However, I'm a bit stuck in terms of the mathematical tools I have to work with.    Can anyone point me in a good direction?  Here is an example function that I'm working with.  In particular, I want functions for the variables $\theta_i$.  I'm perfectly fine with series approximations or implicit functions as long as they are computable.

$A sin(\theta_1) = -B sin(\theta_2)  $ (1)

$A cos(\theta_1) sin(\theta_3) = -B cos(\theta_2) sin(\theta_4)$ (2)

$A cos(\theta_3)cos(\theta_1) = -B cos(\theta_4)cos(\theta_2)$ (3)

with constraints that A and B are always positive, and I specify what they are (that is, they are not free parameters, only the $\theta_i$ are).

Now, I feel that since these functions will exclusively work with trigonometric functions, there is a general approach I can take, but I'm not sure.

If it makes much of a difference, the actual equations come from screw theory, which apparently has roots in abstract algebra, specifically Lie algebras.  Is it possible this will help, or will that just overly complicate my life?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer to my question was to first turn it into a system of polynomial equations with a change of variables.  For example, $u1 = sin(\theta_1)$ and $y1 = cos(\theta_1)$, and then add additional equations to force them to lie on the unit circle ($u_1^2 + y_1^2 = 1$), then to approach the problem as a system of polynomial equations that are simultaneously zero.